# Empty state for pagination in android jetpack compose recomposes & shows flickering

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

I have a Flow<PagingData> in my viewmodel.
In my compose UI screen I collect it as follows
`val transactionHistoryItems = transactionHistoryViewModel.transactionHistoryPager.collectAsLazyPagingItems()`

And below this I have a scaffold & in its content I have the following

```
if (transactionHistoryItems.isEmpty()) {
                        EmptyDataScreen(
                            iconResId = R.drawable.ic_empty_transaction_list_screen,
                            message = stringResource(
                                id = if (isAnyTagActive) R.string.np_transaction_list_no_search_result
                                else R.string.empty_transaction_history_list_message
                            )
                        )
                    }
    else  {
 ShowActualUI()
}
```

The issues is that whenever something changes & UI is in empty state condition then that part recomposes & empty UI flickers. How can I avoid this ?

This is the extension function that I use for calculating empty state

`fun <T : Any> LazyPagingItems<T>.isEmpty(): Boolean { return (loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && itemCount == 0) }`